# Background Color Randomly Changes of UIViewController presented Modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I have a `UIViewController`(AViewController) that has a UIButton that modally presents another UIViewController (BViewController). BViewController has a UIVisualEffectView that blurs AViewController. In storyboard, I have set the background color to 0% opacity of the following: the View of the BViewController, and the UIVisualEffectView and its View. So it should be completely transparent except and just have the blurring effect.

Most of the time this works as expected. However, about 1 out of 3 times (but randomly i.e. I can't find a pattern) the background of ViewController is dark grey instead of clear. And it is not transparent.

I have tried to programmatically ensure that the color is clear. If I set the backgrounds (of BViewController and the UIVisualEffectView and its View) to clearColor in viewDidLoad, nothing changes i.e. it works about every 3 out of 4 times. However, if I set the backgrounds in viewDidAppear then it turns the exact color of dark grey and not transparent at all EVERY TIME (instead of 1 out 3 times).

The code is straight forward and the UIViewControllers are set up in storyboard.

In AViewController

```
var aViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AViewController") as! 

self.presentViewController(aViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

In BViewController

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

**EDIT: SIMPLE TEST PROJECT IN XCODE TO REPLICATE ISSUE **

This is giving me dark grey background 9/10 times - making me realize that I have never presented a modal UIViewController without a segue before.

BViewController

```
class BViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func exit(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

AViewController

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func present(sender: AnyObject) {
        var bViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("bViewController") as! BViewController

        self.presentViewController(bViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample project that reliably reproduces the issue? There's not enough here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AaronBrager I will work on putting one together now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AaronBrager I posted code - I realized that I have never presented modal VC without a segue before so hopefully I didn't ask this question prematurely.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you use for make background-color clear

Answer (score 0):

***With Segue in connection***

To my knowledge it is happening because when ever you present a view controller with a segue it gets presented over the view controller that it is connected to and is also put in the current stack only i.e the stack in which the ViewControllerA was.

***Without segue in connection i.e INITIATING a ViewController***

But when you INITIATE a view controller  i.e ViewControllerB it gets loaded in a new stack and hence it doesn't find any view controller below it and because of that it show a dark grey or black color when making the Main View of ViewControllerB's color to CLEAR Color.

//I hope i was able to convey my self and was helpful to you. Happy Coding :)